# Compare Date 1 and Date 2 with 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is how I calculate the duration:

```
var duration = new Date().getTime() - customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTime();
```

This is how I compare:

```
var TEN_MINUTES = 10*60*1000;

if(duration > TEN_MINUTES){
//do smtg
}
```

`new Date().getTime()` returns `1528291351108` which is `Wed Jun 06 2018 13:22:31` in UTC

`customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime` returns `Wed Jun 06 2018 13:20:04 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)` in my code.

`customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTime()` returns `1528262404000` which is `Wed Jun 06 2018 05:20:04` in UTC

In database, `customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime` is in `UTC format` but when I retrieve it, it shows the local timezone. How can I set this to UTC format too when I retrieve it in node.js using Sequelize ?

Comment: Hi have you tried: `new Date(customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime).getTime()` ?

Comment: yes. it is not showing the right value in UTC. @t3__rry

Comment: Ok, if you need to convert to a specific timezone take a look at the built-in methods in the docs ex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString
If you need a lib `moment.js`is great (but huge) https://momentjs.com/ and `moment-timezone`http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Answer (score 0):

I had to add 8 hours to get time in UTC

```
var timeInUTC = customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTime() - (customerForgotPassword[0].createdTime.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000)
```